# Apache NiFi irregular data flow through Remote Process Groups

Tags: apache-nifi

I am in the process of evaluating *Apache NiFi* for use in a project. I have four instances of *NiFi* v1.1.2 running in the cloud on *Ubuntu 14* systems. Three of the instances are acting as Remote Process Groups (`R1`, `R2` & `R3`) and the remaining instance (`M1`) is used to manage the flow between the RPGs.
`M1` generates a FlowFile, passes the FlowFile through a pipeline consisting of the three RPGs, and logs the FlowFile at the end.
Each RPG simply appends `R{id}` to a *ProcessedBy* attribute in the FlowFile so the the order in which the data is processed can be easily seen.

The problem I have is the order is not as expected 100% of the time. I use 2 pipelines (`P1` & `P2`) that traverse the RPGs in the order `R1->R2->R3` and `R2->R1->R3` respectively.
What I am seeing is that ~50% of the time the FlowFile in `P1` is not processed by `R2`, while in `P2` it actually reverses direction and is processed by `R2` twice so the flow order becomes `R2->R1->R2->R3`

**Edit:**

Here is an image of my flow in `M1` [image: NiFi Flow]

Comment: Can you share an image of the flow?  How do you segregate traffic for P1 vs. P2?  Have you looked at the provenance events from sample flowfiles to see their paths?

Comment: @James to segregate traffic for `P1` & `P2` I either run one or the other. I am looking at the data provenance events but it doesn't actually give me any information about the cause. I can see the path of the FlowFile moving through the pipeline but I can't see what's causing the incorrect flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe Remote Process Groups behave with kind of "function semantics" you are expecting.  The odd flowfile traffic pattern is happening because flowfiles originating on the left of your flow are emerging from RPG outputs on the right (and the reverse), but this is correct behavior for an RPG output port.

Sending a flowfile to a remote flow from one input port does not guarantee that it will "return" via the output port on the same RPG diagram node.  Multiple listeners to a remote output port will each individually receive a share of the outputs.  Visually connecting an RPG input with it's output is typical, recommended, and arguably the most self-explanatory way to organize your flow.  But it is not required.

You could create different named ports on the remote NiFis to give you more remote input/output options.

I made a sample flow using only two NiFi's, with node1.nifi sending to and receiving from a Remote Process Group on the node2.nifi.
I organized the flow to emphasize the potentially disconnected relationship between the RPG input and output ports.

[image: NiFi Remote Process Groups]

The three RPG graph nodes all reference the same RPG on node2.nifi, but inputs and outputs are separated.  Output is received in two locations, which has resulted in a slightly unequal distribution.

Comment: Thanks @James I didn't realise that inputs/outputs worked in this way, the results I am seeing make complete sense now.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to have an RPG that is reusable without modification i.e. it can be used in many pipelines simultaneously and will return the processed data to the sending pipeline every time. Is there a "best practise" approach to achieving this?

Comment: One option would be an HTTP service using InvokeHttp on the client and HandleHttpRequest...HandleHttpResponse on the server.  This would provide the best fit to the call and response pattern.

Comment: Using RPGs, I think you would have to add your own logic to track the origins of flowfiles and send them back to their originating server.  If the numbers were small, you could use multiple input and output ports to clarify which traffic is which.